# How to open/install a config file in iOS

Tags: android, ios, xcode, react-native

I have a React Native app in Android and iOS.  The app downloads a profile configuration file (filename.mobileconfig) which I download from an API and open which prompts the user to install.

On android I achieved this using `actionViewIntent`;

```
 RNFetchBlob.android.actionViewIntent(dirs.DocumentDir + '/passpoint.config.xml', 'application/x-wifi-config')
      .then(() => { console.log('File install started...') })
      .catch((err) => { err });
```

And the above works fine on Android.

But on iOS, I have the file downloaded but not sure how I can invoke the installation as I do on Android.
I tried using;

```
 RNFetchBlob.ios.openDocument(resp.data);
```

But this does not work as I expect as it only shows me a screen with a white background and the filename centered on the screen.

I expect a prompt from the OS to appear on the screen asking the user to install the configuration file as it does on Android.

Any help is appreciated.